# Retrieving drawn Rectangle2D object and read it's properties

Tags: java, swing

I am drawing a rectangle from method `DrawRect` using swings like this -

```
 Graphics2D graph2 = (Graphics2D) g;
 Rectangle2D rect = new Rectangle2D.Double(100, 100, 100, 100);
 graph2.draw(rect);
```

In other method `getDrawnRect`, I want to get that object of drawn rectangle and read its properties.

I mean, is there any method available that returns objects drawn (like rectangles,circles) or any other way to get those objects indirectly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the local variable `Rectangle2D rect` define a field of the class. During drawing store the rect to the field and then your `getDrawnRect()` method should return the stored rectangle field

Comment: Yes.I can do that. But my question is how to get that object.I mean is there any method that would return all objects on the frame?

Comment: There are no *objects on the frame*. If you need drawn objects store them.